# Guardar en una columna todos los registros depende de una condicion laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, function, formato-condicional, guardar

Tengo una funcion en mi controlador que se encarga de confirmar si cada registro cumple con el puntaje correspondiente. quisiera saber como guardar en una columna todos los puntajes que le corresponda.

Esta es mi tabla

```
Schema::create('puntaje', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('nombre')->nullable();
    $table->integer('carrera1')->nullable();
    $table->integer('carr1pos1')->nullable();
    $table->integer('carr1pos2')->nullable();
    $table->integer('carr1pos3')->nullable();
    $table->string('puntos')->nullable()->default(0);
});
```

```
public function index()
{
    $puntajes= Puntaje::all();
    foreach ($puntajes as $puntaje) {
        $primer=5;
        $segundo=3;
        $tercero=1;
        $pierde=0;
        $total=0;
            
        switch ($puntaje->carrera1) {
            case $puntaje->carr1pos1:
                echo $primer;
                $total=$total+$primer;
                break;
            case $puntaje->carr1pos2:
                echo $segundo;
                break;
            case $puntaje->carr1pos3:
                echo $tercero;
                break;
                
            default:
                echo $pierde;
                break;
                    
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de como deseas los datos en la columna?

Comment: puedes hacer el update a los tres primeros lugares y a los demas haces un update masivo, concretamente de donde sacas la posición ?

Comment: Si quiero guardarlo en mi base de datos masivamente en la columna puntos. Cada uno con su respectivo puntaje